# Oracle Merge ignore duplicates

Tags: oracle, merge

I have a table accessible via an oracle database link, which I'm attempting to pull into a local database table because reasons.

```
MERGE INTO MEMBERSHIPS LOCAL
USING (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    REMOTE.GROUP_NAME        "GROUP_NAME",
    REMOTE.USER_ACCOUNT      "USERNAME",
    REMOTE.SOME_OTHER_COLUMN "COL3"
  FROM MEMBERSHIPS@link REMOTE
) REMOTE
ON (
  REMOTE.GROUP_NAME = LOCAL.GROUP_NAME AND
  REMOTE.USERNAME   = LOCAL.USERNAME
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    LOCAL.COL3       = REMOTE.COL3
    LOCAL.UPDATED_AT = sysdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ID, GROUP_NAME, USERNAME, COl3, CREATED_AT, UPDATED_AT)
  VALUES (MEMBERSHIPS_SEQ.NEXTVAL, REMOTE.GROUP_NAME, REMOTE.USERNAME, REMOTE.COl3, sysdate, sysdate)
```

Most unfortunately, the owner of the original database has not lost much sleep worrying about data integrity, so in the 3 millionish rows, there are 71 duplicates, which blows up my Unique Index on Group Name, Username. The merge will process if I remove the uniqueness constraint, however these rows will then blow up on a subsequent execution of the query with a `ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables`.

This is the sort of thing that will get run on a daily basis, so I need to  find a way to ignore duplicates

EDIT:

I would have thought the distinct would have took care of the problem for me, but it doesn't. I still get duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
REMOTE.GROUP_NAME,
REMOTE.USER_ACCOUNT
COUNT(*)
FROM MEMBERSHIPS@link REMOTE
GROUP BY
REMOTE.GROUP_NAME,
REMOTE.USER_ACCOUNT
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Shows 71 GROUP_NAME/USER_ACCOUNT combinations that are still duplicated

Comment: confused:  why doesn't the DISTINCT take care of the duplicates?  do you have duplicates locally but with other values in the ID and dates?

Comment: The local table is empty, and gets a uniqueness violation when it encounters the first duplicate, the distinct does not appear to get rid of the duplicates as I had hoped. The local ID and timestamps are the only fields not coming straight from the source table.

Comment: is there also an ID on the remote table?  perhaps select the MIN ID and group by the other columns to get only one row...

Comment: There is no, unfortunately.

Comment: In the query you added to show that `DISTINCT` does not remove duplicates, you are grouping first, so by definition the `DISTINCT` does nothing as each grouping will have a unique query.  A better test would be `SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT group_name || '.' || user_account) FROM memberships@link`.

Answer (score 3):

In similar situation you can always try to rank rows to avoid duplicates, instead of DISTINCT.
In this case it would be something like that:

```
MERGE INTO MEMBERSHIPS LOCAL
USING (
  SELECT rank() over(partition by REMOTE.GROUP_NAME
        ,REMOTE.USER_ACCOUNT
        order by NVL(REMOTE.UPDATED_AT,REMOTE.CREATED_AT) DESC NULLS LAST) r,
    REMOTE.GROUP_NAME        "GROUP_NAME",
    REMOTE.USER_ACCOUNT      "USERNAME",
    REMOTE.SOME_OTHER_COLUMN "COL3"`
  FROM MEMBERSHIPS@link REMOTE ) REMOTE
ON (
  REMOTE.GROUP_NAME = LOCAL.GROUP_NAME 
  AND REMOTE.USERNAME   = LOCAL.USERNAME
  AND REMOTE.r = 1
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    LOCAL.COL3       = REMOTE.COL3
    LOCAL.UPDATED_AT = sysdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ID, GROUP_NAME, USERNAME, COl3, CREATED_AT, UPDATED_AT)
  VALUES (MEMBERSHIPS_SEQ.NEXTVAL, REMOTE.GROUP_NAME, REMOTE.USERNAME, REMOTE.COl3, sysdate, sysdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the problem you describe, using two local tables.  With the merge as you've provided it, I have no problems caused by duplicates in the source table (in Oracle 11.2.0.4).  If I remove the `DISTINCT` keyword from the subquery in the `USING` clause, then I get exactly the problems you have described - constraint violations in the first attempt, or ORA-30926 in the second attempt if I remove the unique constraint.

The two explanations I can think of for this are that (a) you are hitting some bug in Oracle, possibly involving DISTINCT in remote subqueries, or (b) the merge statement you have actually been running doesn't include that `DISTINCT`.  (I also considered the possibility that NULL values might be causing unexpected results from the DISTINCT operations, but I couldn't come up with a way that would happen.)

EDIT:
Another half-thought-out explanation - if the two databases use different character sets, I wonder if it is possible that values that are distinct in the original table are getting converted in transit to identical values?

Comment: I updated my example. The problem with the distinct is that I'm pulling in other columns. In the source table, most of these other columns are null, but the distinct still takes null into account as a difference.